# Trignometry.. Even Odd Properties

Tags: trigonometry

So we have this even/odd properties in trigonometry and we had this problem:

$\sec (-(\frac{\pi}6))$

And ok i was like first off i can change the - because of even odd properties so it becomes:

$-(\sec(\frac{\pi}6))$

So next I substitute $\sec$ to $\frac1{\cos}$ ....

$-(\frac1{\cos (\frac{\pi}6)}))$

There I get $-2$ ... but the answer is $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$
I really don't understand what I did wrong here... And I figured out that she was right.. I searched up the question online and it did give the answer? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the even/odd property of $\sec$ wrong.  $$\sec(-x)=\sec(x)$$

Comment: @Dsafds np, just a minor issue.  You also evaluated $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}6\right)$ incorrectly.

Comment: Hmm i will take note of that too! Thanks! Now i dont know which anwser to accept.. I had such an obvious anwser both of you got it...

Comment: Isnt Cos pie/6 =  1/2??

Comment: @Dsafds No, it should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$, as Kf-Sansoo noted.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake.... I was thinking about pie/3 ..  $\frac{\pi}3$

Comment: @Dsafds Right click on any of my fractions, 'show math as', MathML Code.  You can copy/paste my coding and edit the numbers or parts as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

$\sec\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)= \dfrac{1}{\cos\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)}= \dfrac{1}{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)}= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}= \dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: Like Simple Art said i had the sec even property wrong! Man im stupid..... Sorry for irritance!